# Selenium Python: Neither Element Click or .send_keys work on this webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

On [this](https://orderz.sheetz.com/#/main/location/search) webpage, I cannot figure out how to enter text into the search box or select a given state from the dropdown menu. It seems pretty simple as I have done this with other websites, but I can't figure it out.

**Attempt 1 (selecting from dropdown):**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://orderz.sheetz.com/#/main/location/search")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="state-search"]/select/option[2]').click()
```

**Attempt 2 (entering text into search):**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://orderz.sheetz.com/#/main/location/search")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="storeSearchForm"]/div/div/input').send_keys("pa", Keys.ENTER)
```

**Error message for Attempt 1:**

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="state-search"]/select/option[2]"}
```

**Error message for Attempt 2:**

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="storeSearchForm"]/div/div/input"}
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Webpage is not opening for me. Could you check if that webelement is in iframe?

Comment: https://www.sheetz.com/, then click top right corner "Find A Sheetz"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use JavaScript executor to click the web element.

Please refer link : https://dzone.com/articles/perform-actions-using-javascript-in-python-seleniu

Comment: @jack, Still are you facing the same blocker?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Have you been able to get it to work?